# How to pass Integer[] using bundles in android?

Tags: android

```
      Integer[] image = { 
       R.drawable.image1,
       R.drawable.image22,

   };
```

how can i pass this array using bundle?

Answer (score 2):

by using ArrayList we can send

```
private ArrayList<Integer> image;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    image = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    image.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    image.add(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {              

            Intent intent = new Intent(PhotoActivity.this,PhotoActivity1.class ); 
            intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("VALUES", image);               
            startActivity(cameraIntent); 
        }     
    });
```

in the receiver class

```
Intent i = getIntent();
ArrayList<Integer> img = i.getIntegerArrayListExtra("VALUES");
```

Comment: when i tried this line bundle.putExtra("VALUES", image);i am getting error as - method putExtra(String, Integer[]) is undefined for the type Bundle

Comment: @ RajaReddy: Thanksa lot for your answer.  How can i get this intent in another class.

Comment: we can't pass Integer[] values, if it is required for you use ArrayList<Integer>..

Answer (score 1):

First of all for Sending

```
Bundle bnd=new Bundle();
bnd.putStringArray(key, new String[]{value1, value2});
Intent i=new Intent(context, Class);
i.putExtras(bnd);
```

Then at Receiving side

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array=b.getStringArray(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this alternative:

```
int[] image = { 
       R.drawable.image1,
       R.drawable.image22,

   };
String key = "INT_ARRAY_KEY";
```

Sending activity:

```
Bundle bnd=new Bundle();
bnd.putIntArray(key, image);
Intent i=new Intent(sendingActivity, receivingActivity.class);
i.putExtras(bnd);
```

Receiving activity:

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
int[] imageArray=b.getIntArray(key);
```